# JS/Mongoose: Update element of array based on sort position of another value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm making a quizapplication. After a round of 12 questions I want to award points to all teams that have partaken in the round. Team with the most correct answers gets 3 points, second team gets 2 points, third team gets 1 point and the rest of the teams get 0.1 point for the effort.
So far i can get the array sorted based on correctly answered questions, but i don't know how to update the pointamount (since multiple rounds will be played, the new pointamount needs to be points = points + the amount of points the team should get based on its position this round)

The current database looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ok9S.png). correctCount are the amount of correct questions this round(gets reset after eacht round) and points is the amount of points this team had(since its the first round all teams have 0 points)

The code currently looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k39ma.png)

And the json output currently looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kDb9.png)

I can make it so it displays all teams as well, at the moment its limited to showing the second to lowest score. I tried using $set, but this did nothing for me.

I hope someone can help me. It's my first javascript project. I'm making this as an assignment and am stuck on this part.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an alternative approach, you can use `polpulate()` function to populate your teams. after that modify each team as you see fit and save() the whole game. that way your changes will take effect and the code is simpler to manipulate.

Comment: Teams are made at the beginning of the game and already exist. Populate works with populating a field with data from another collection. Since I don't have another collection, I don't have anything tot populate it with?